# Not able to display the Arabic character in command line

Tags: java

Not able to display the Arabic character in the windows command line. I am able to print the Arabic text locally (in the Eclipse console). But the same jar run through the command line  Arabic text is not printing. I have used the below code snippet

```
String arabicText = "للبطاقة المنتهية برقم";
byte[] arabicTextBytes = arabicText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String rawText = new String(arabicTextBytes);
```

******Working as expected in Eclipse Console:******

raw text:------>للبطاقة المنتهية برقم`enter code here` >
**In Command Line:**

raw Text :----> Ù„Ù„Ø¨Ø·Ø§Ù‚Ø© Ø§Ù„Ù…Ù†ØªÙ‡ÙŠØ© Ø¨Ø±Ù‚Ù…`enter code here`

Comment: Could it be that the dev environment doesn't have the needed Arabic fonts installed?

Comment: How to configure Arabic fonts in Dev environment?

Comment: It looks like the (Windows?) command prompt is configured with some other character encoding than UTF-8 ... which is what you have hard-wired your Java code to use.  (The code page for UTF-8 is apparently 65001.)  You will also need Arabic fonts installed.

Comment: Hi Stephen, listing properties --
java.runtime.name=Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
sun.boot.library.path=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251\bin
java.vm.version=25.251-b08
java.vm.vendor=Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url=http://java.oracle.com/
path.separator=;
java.vm.name=Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
user.script=
user.country=IN sun.jnu.encoding=Cp1252 file.encoding=UTF-8
sun.cpu.endian=little
sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeLittle
sun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8

Comment: What output do you get when you run `chcp` at the command prompt?

Comment: D:\Test>chcp
Active code page: 1252